# Angular SQL "limit" error

Tags: php, angularjs

I've got a simple angular sql-php-json data fetching.

The code works until some record. Then it's trows an error.
It works with 51 record, crashes with 52... Obviously I need all the data. :)

What am I missing?
Thank you.

Console error:

```
{}
```

javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get(file)
      .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;},
        function(error) {console.log(JSON.stringify(error));}
     );
  });
```

php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");    
include("connect.php");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, nev, cim, kapcsolat, bankszamlaszam, adoszam FROM szallito ORDER BY nev LIMIT 52"); 

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"id":"'  . $rs["id"].'",';
    $outp .= '"nev":"'. $rs["nev"].'",';
    $outp .= '"cim":"'. $rs["cim"].'",';
    $outp .= '"kapcsolat":"'. $rs["kapcsolat"].'",';
    $outp .= '"bankszamlaszam":"'. $rs["bankszamlaszam"].'",';
    $outp .= '"adoszam":"'  . $rs["adoszam"].'"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
```

Comment: Should be stringify. You could consider deleting the post if it's just a typo. I don't think this post will help others.

Comment: While `JSON.stringify` is spelled wrong - that's only prohibiting OP from logging the error - fix the typo and please post the actual error you're receiving from the server.

Comment: I've changed it, the error remains. I mean the new error is: {}

Answer (score 1):

It is JSON.stringify

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't helped, like I said the error remains... which is like this in the console.log -> {}  (that's all what it says, and crashes. )